# Coloring the area between circle and path in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

I'm new to tikz and for my thesis all the drawings I've made were in https://www.mathcha.io/editor and now the drawing I need to do can't done there so I need to code. The drawing I did is this[image: 1] and I would like to fill the area between the circle and the path (the outer part). I tried using the \fillbetween but haven't figured it out and I can't figure it out.  The code I used is

```
\documentclass[tipotesi=triennale]{toptesi}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=5];
%\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(-4,0) (1,1) (3,1) (3,0) (4,-1)};
\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(-4,0) (-2,-4) (0,-3) (2,-3) (3,-2.5) (4,0) (1,2) (0,4) (-1,4.5) (-3,0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you can combine both paths, that of the circle and that of the blob, in one single `\fill` macro and set the fill rule to even-odd using the option `even odd rule`:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[even odd rule, red] (0,0) circle [radius=5]
    plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(-4,0) (-2,-4) (0,-3) (2,-3) (3,-2.5) (4,0) (1,2) (0,4) (-1,4.5) (-3,0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]